# English-to-Japanese dictionary with a free license like JMdict?

Tags: discussion

[JMdict](http://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/JMdict-EDICT_Dictionary_Project) is the popular liberally-licensed Japanese-to-English dictionary that powers all the websites and apps for English speakers learning Japanese.

Are there any projects that go in the opposite direction, i.e., freely-licensed dictionaries going from English-to-Japanese for Japanese speakers learning English?

I'm aware of several *commercial* English-to-Japanese dictionaries (the topic was discussed recently on JMdict's [mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/edict-jmdict/CANy6PaVpCraNvdVA%3DphO2OQNbFBn4W68y_NCo8qatD7irQ%2BrDQ%40mail.gmail.com)) but I'm specifically looking for projects with free licenses (or with easily-obtained licenses).

Searching past questions, I just realized that one example is [Japanese Wiktionary](https://ja.wiktionary.org) and am interested in learning of others.